# Add element not duplicated on arraylist with different index and size

Tags: java, arraylist

i've 2 ArrayList

ArrayList users formed by 2 columns: `[2, 1, 2, 2]` `2` rappresent the id of the user while `1 and 2` is the id of the service

ArrayList services call `tmp` formed by 1 column: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]`

I want to compare the second column of arraylist users with every element of arraylist services and if they are different put the id of the user and id of service in another array formed by 2 columns

The result I want is:

```
[2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2, 10, 2, 11, 2, 12, 2, 13, 2, 14, 2, 15, 2, 16, 2, 17, 2, 18, 2, 19, 2, 20, 2, 21, 2, 22, 2, 23, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2, 10, 2, 11, 2, 12, 2, 13, 2, 14, 2, 15, 2, 16, 2, 17, 2, 18, 2, 19, 2, 20, 2, 21, 2, 22, 2, 23]
```

I try but doesn't work well

```
for(int i=0;i<users.size();i+=2)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<tmp.size();j++)
                {
                    if(users.get(i+1).equals(tmp.get(j)))
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tmp2.add(users.get(i));
                        tmp2.add(tmp.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
```

wrong output:

```
[2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2, 10, 2, 11, 2, 12, 2, 13, 2, 14, 2, 15, 2, 16, 2, 17, 2, 18, 2, 19, 2, 20, 2, 21, 2, 22, 2, 23, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2, 10, 2, 11, 2, 12, 2, 13, 2, 14, 2, 15, 2, 16, 2, 17, 2, 18, 2, 19, 2, 20, 2, 21, 2, 22, 2, 23]
```

the output should start from `[2,3 .......]`

Comment: It really is not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: in array users i have 2 columns: first column indicate id of user, secondo column indicate id of service

Comment: in arraylist services i have 1 column that is the id of all services

Comment: What exactly does not work well?

Comment: i want to compare the second column of arraylist users with first column of arraylist services and then put in another array call tmp2 the id of the services wich not appear in the second column of arraylist users

Comment: @AlexZam i update with the wrong ouput

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect ids that does not appear in `users` array then iterating `users` in outer loop is wrong: you add elements to `tmp2` before even looking at second "record" of `users`.

You should exchange them like this:

```
for(int service : tmp) {
  boolean found = false;
  for(int i = 0; i < users.size(); i += 2) {
    if(users.get(i+1) == service) found = true;
  }

  if(!found) {
    for (int i...) { 
      tmp2.add(users.get(i));
      tmp2.add(service);
    }
  }
}
```

Of course it is bad practice to have "2 column" lists. Consider making `User` class with 2 fields. And using streams would help to create more readable code.

Comment: `tmp2.add(users.get(i));` the index 'i' generate error

Comment: `errore: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2`

Comment: all 3 arrays are arraylist of string

Comment: Ok you are right, my bad. But what exactly do you want? Find in `tmp` services that do not exist in `users`? Then write to `tmp2` pairs of each user and that not-found service? May be done if you change "tmp2.add" statements to loop through users (again) with `add` calls in the body. Strange task although.